# Enable autosubmit ONLY for sort exposed filter in Drupal Views

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-views

I have an exposed filter block with multiple select filters including "sort by" type of filter. All filter values are submitted by pressing "Apply" button.

I want to give auto-submit function only for "sort" filter. I've found the code below, but it doesn't work even though it should. Is it even possible to target only a single filter?

Code:

`$('.views-exposed-form select').change(function() {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
 });`

Any tips would be very appreciated!

Comment: Tag jQuery $ if it represent jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Wait until document fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Check if the filter exists
    if($('.views-exposed-form select').length){
        // Your change function
        $('.views-exposed-form select').change(function() {
            // Submit the form
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That's great! Needed just to change "views-exposed-form" to specific filter class and works nicely. Thanks for the help!